How to deploy to server a image in Docker Hub
I'm doing back-end spring boot web application REST api, database from sql server 2019. Here is what I done right now :

I already create image in docker, run in localhost successfull.
After that, I push it in Docker Hub
Now I want to deploy it in server to easy to use api
Here is my Dockerfile and application.properties, I haven't docker-compose.yml yet :

Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

application.properties:
spring.application.name=diamondStore
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal:1435;databaseName=DiamondStore;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Diamond12@
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

Can you guy suggest any idea ?
If in cloud platform, I'm trying to use Azure, Azure Student. But I don't know how to do right ?

You need at least two lines in your Dockerfile
docker login credentials
docker image pull yourimage

If you are using Azure,you should read the docs azure container create,but you can do that with
az container create -g resourceGroup -n Name --image yourimage --ports 

